# Simple, fast SQL queries for flat files

Tags: sql, linux, sorting, flat-file

Does anyone know of any tools to provide simple, fast queries of flat files using a SQL-like declarative query language?  I'd rather not pay the overhead of loading the file into a DB since the input data is typically thrown out almost immediately after the query is run.

Consider the data file, "animals.txt":

```
dog 15
cat 20
dog 10
cat 30
dog 5
cat 40
```

Suppose I want to extract the highest value for each unique animal.  I would like to write something like:

```
cat animals.txt | foo "select $1, max(convert($2 using decimal)) group by $1"
```

I can get nearly the same result using `sort`:

```
cat animals.txt | sort -t " " -k1,1 -k2,2nr
```

And I can always drop into `awk` from there, but this all feels a bit `awk`ward (couldn't resist) when a SQL-like language would seem to solve the problem so cleanly.

I've considered writing a wrapper for SQLite that would automatically create a table based on the input data, and I've looked into using Hive in single-processor mode, but I can't help but feel this problem has been solved before.  Am I missing something?  Is this functionality already implemented by another standard tool?

Halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to find a satisfying answer to my question, but I did at least find a solution to my toy problem using `uniq`s "-f" option, which I had been unaware of:

```
cat animals.txt | sort -t " " -k1,1 -k2,2nr \
| awk -F' ' '{print $2, " ", $1}' | uniq -f 1
```

The `awk` portion above could, obviously, be skipped entirely if the input file were created with columns in the opposite order.

I'm still holding out hope for a SQL-like tool, though.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [TxtSushi](http://keithsheppard.name/txt-sushi/) mostly to do SQL selects on flat files. Here is the command chain for your example (all of these commands are from TxtSushi):

```
tabtocsv animals.txt | namecolumns - | tssql -table animals - \
'select col1, max(as_int(col2)) from animals group by col1'
```

namecolumns is only required because animals.txt doesn't have a header row. You can get a quick sense of what is possible by looking through the [example scripts](http://patch-tag.com/r/keithshep/txt-sushi/snapshot/current/content/pretty/examples). There are also links to similar tools on the bottom of the main page.

Comment: Very nice.  How well does it scale?  I'm hoping to deal with muti-gigabyte files which exceed the available RAM on my machine.

Comment: It does any kind of row filtering or column selection using a streaming approach but as soon as you ask it to do anything requiring a sort (group by, join on, order by all require sorts) it wants to read the full table into memory. In this case you can give the -external-sort option which tells TxtSushi to sort on disk instead, but my current implementation of external sort is very inefficient and needs some work.

Answer (score 1):

Perl DBI using [DBD::AnyData](http://search.cpan.org/~jzucker/DBD-AnyData-0.09/AnyData.pm)

Answer (score 1):

you can use sqlite. Here's an example using Python.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("""create table table1 (word varchar not null, number varchar not null)""")
except: pass
cursor.execute("insert into table1 values ('dog', '15')")
cursor.execute("insert into table1 values ('cat', '20')")
cursor.execute("insert into table1 values ('dog', '10')")
cursor.execute("select max(number) , word from table1 group by word")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
[(u'20', u'cat'), (u'15', u'dog')]
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to do everything right from the shell, which this solution doesn't seem to support.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across [this Python script](http://www.gl1tch.com/~lukewarm/software/csvq/) which does something like what you want, although it only supports very basic queries.

Answer (score 0):

We'll I have a [lightweight ORM for sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite) that would simplify this task without requiring any configuration files, etc.

If you can using PowerShell has a lot of powerful capabilities for parsing and querying text files ([example here](http://www.candland.net/blog/2007/05/08/SumAColumnInATabdelimitedFileUsingPowershell.aspx)). Otherwise using .NET/Mono you can cut that up in and use LINQ in no time.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do everything right from the shell, which this solution doesn't seem to support.

Comment: Which one? Powershell is bash on steroids which lets you do everything from the shell. As for OrmLite (which is what I would use), you write a few lines program that imports all the data to your db of choice then you can use the sqlite3.exe to query from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool that might help.
http://www.mccoyonlinestore.com/index.php?txtSearch=mccoy_rdbms
your sql could be "Select Max(value) from animals"
or it could by "Select * from animals order by value desc"

Answer (score 0):

You can look for [HXTT JDBC Drivers](http://www.hxtt.com/). They provide JDBC drivers for most type of flat files, excel etc .

You can execute simple SQL queries on it.

They have trial versions available as well